# Returning variable-width data by value in C

Tags: c, assembly, memory-management

I'm looking for a way to write a function in C that returns a string of bytes by value. **I know** that this is usually solved by allocating from the heap, or by making the caller pass a pointer to some buffer. However, in my case, the function must not do any heap allocations for performance reasons (so no malloc, just alloca), and the string length is determined by the function, so there's no way for the caller to know how much space to allocate for it, and there is no defined maximum length either. I also can't split the function into two halves; one that determines the length and one that generates the string.

In short, the callee **must** be the one that determines the length, allocates the string **on stack** and fills it. When the function returns, the caller may need to do some fancy stuff in order to store the string safely, but again, it must be stored **on the stack**, and without calling the function multiple times.

I know this isn't good practice, this would only be used in computer-generated C code. I don't suppose this can be done in "safe" standard C, since everything allocated on the stack is scoped and dies on scope exit. But in reality, those values are still somewhere on the stack (at least until they are overridden), even though the C standard says that reading them is undefined behavior. Does anybody know some good way to do this on x86/x86_64?

Comment: Is this a C question or an assembly question? In assembly, the called function can manipulate the stack in whatever way is required, returning a value that tells the caller what has been left on the stack, for it to use and subsequently clean up.

Comment: This is almost certainly an XY-problem. Also, your plan to horrifically break the rules of C and the platform ABI will not work.

Comment: How big is the buffer, realistically?

Comment: There *is* a maximum length because the stack size is limited. Typically, stack size is a few megabytes, whereas total memory is a few gigabytes. So nothing stops you from declaring a `static` buffer inside the function that's big enough.

Comment: For every "it must be like this" statement from your question, please give a reason _why_ it must be so. Or tell us directly what higher level problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @RolandIllig The main reason is curiosity. I was wondering if it could be done without splitting the function into two parts, but that seems to be the only viable solution.

Comment: @user3386109 The stack is that small on Windows; on Linux I find it's usually a lot bigger. Besides, the stack size can be specified when creating a thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't ever do this, it's nasty.  The way [`snprintf(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) works is usually good (see below)

I did manage to achieve this under limited circumstances (user-space code on Linux, with some empty inline-asm statements to defeat the optimizer, see implementation below), **by having the caller claim the returned buffer (below its stack pointer) with its own `alloca`**.  This expands the caller's stack frame to include the buffer (i.e. puts RSP below it), in a way that the compiler knows about/understands, preventing it from synchronously clobbering your data.

The major weakness is that your data is below ESP/RSP temporarily.  You need to avoid asynchronous clobbering of the data by avoiding signal handlers entirely, or using an alternate signal stack (so you have an effectively infinite [red-zone](/questions/tagged/red-zone)).  If you can't do that (e.g. in kernel code where interrupt handlers will use the current stack), you can't avoid a window of vulnerability where your data below ESP/RSP could be asynchronous clobbered.  (i.e. you can't use this.)

Without an infinite red-zone, I think the only way to really do this is to write both the caller and callee in assembly language, so the caller is expecting the callee to return with a different RSP.  (Normally, RSP is call-preserved, and copying the return address somewhere else before running a RET instruction will break things.)

[@DavidHoltzer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226983/returning-variable-width-data-by-value-in-c#comment67719621_40227159) that you might manage to do something with inline-asm, but messing around with the caller's EBP and returning with ESP modified will only work if you force the compiler to make a stack frame with EBP in the caller, and somehow make sure it doesn't make any assumptions about ESP relative to EBP.  Maybe if the caller is simple, and you use `__attribute__((noinline))`...

---

**The only truly portable / safe way:  cheat.  Turn your whole "function" into a macro**.  You can use `alloca` (or a C99 variable length array).  Since it's a macro, it happens *inside* the "caller".

`alloca` stays valid until the end of the function, not just the scope (like a C99 VLA), so you could use a GNU C statement-expression to have a macro you can use as `char *p = MY_INSANE_MACRO(arg1, arg2);`

---

**The "normal" way to do this is [the way `snprintf(3)` works](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html)**:

- function takes a buffer and a size as args.
- If the data fits in the buffer, all is good and it returns the size.
- If the data doesn't fit, it returns the size of buffer required.  (`snprintf` fills the buffer up to the end with truncated output, but if the caller is always going to retry, you could just leave the contents undefined.)
- Normally the caller just passes a buffer that's big enough the first time (based on a rough estimate, or just a constant size that's usually good), and everything works with no retry.  In computing, small numbers are extremely common, and optimizing for the small-number case is usually a win.

---

### Tested and working solution, if my assumptions are correct

I *think* signal-handlers are the only thing that can asynchronously clobber the stack in a Linux user-space process.  By using a separate stack for signal handlers, you may be able to have an arbitrary-size red-zone.  [Glibc supports the 4.4BSD `sigaltstack` API](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Signal-Stack.html).

See the code + asm on [the Godbolt compiler explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,options:(colouriseAsm:'0',compileOnChange:'0'),source:'%23include+%3Csignal.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdlib.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cassert.h%3E%0A%0A//+you+might+have+seen+a+macro+like+this+called+ESCAPE%0A%23define+DEFEAT_OPTIMIZER(p)++asm+volatile(%22%22+:+:+%22g%22+(p)+:+%22memory%22)%0A%0A//+writing+this+function+in+assembly+language+might+be+necessary+to+grow+the+buffer+on+the+fly,%0A//+if+it!'s+not+possible+to+work+out+ahead+of+time+how+big+it+needs+to+be.%0A%0A__attribute__((noinline))+++//+otherwise+the+strcpy+just+inlines+into+the+caller+(and+optimizes+away+without+DEFEAT_OPTIMIZER)%0Achar+*return_stackmem(char+*input,+uint32_t+*bufsize)%0A%7B%0A++++//+Figure+out+the+buffer+size+somehow%3B%0A++++*bufsize+%3D+1234%3B%0A++++//+Allocate+some+padding+at+the+top+to+make+sure+the+caller+doesn!'t+step+on%0A++++//+any+part+of+the+buffer+we+will+use.++Hopefully+128B+is+enough...%0A++++char+*buf+%3D+alloca(*bufsize+%2B+128)%3B%0A++%0A++++//+store+into+buf%3B%0A++++strcpy(buf,+%22abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz%22)%3B%0A%0A++++//+clang+normally+optimizes+away+the+strcpy+because+according+to+C+rules,%0A++++//+the+buffer+is+dead+before+anything+can+look+at+our+return+value%0A++++//+current+gcc+doesn!'t+do+that,+but+this+is+definitely+a+good+idea.%0A++++DEFEAT_OPTIMIZER(buf)%3B%0A++++return+buf%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Avoid+insane_caller(char+*input)%0A%7B%0A++++uint32_t+bufsize%3B++//+not+size_t+because+4GB+is+already+more+than+will+work.%0A++++char+*buffer_below_the_stack+%3D+return_stackmem(input,+%26bufsize)%3B%0A%0A++++//+alloca+another+buffer+that+entirely+covers+the+first+one,+placing+RSP+below+the+buffer%0A++++char+*claim_the_space+%3D+alloca(bufsize+%2B+256)%3B++++//+some+extra+padding,+since+the+buffer+probably+wasn!'t+right+at+the+top+of+the+callee!'s+stack+frame.%0A++++DEFEAT_OPTIMIZER(claim_the_space)%3B++//+make+sure+the+alloca+really+happens%0A++++assert(claim_the_space+%3C+buffer_below_the_stack)%3B%0A++++char+*safe_buffer+%3D+buffer_below_the_stack%3B%0A%0A++++printf(%22safe+to+make+further+function+calls+now,+and+do+stuff+like+print+the+buffer:+%25s%5Cn%22,+safe_buffer)%3B%0A++++//+returning+destroys+all+the+alloca()ed+memory%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main(int+argc,+char**argv)+%7B%0A++++stack_t+altstack+%3D+%7B+.ss_sp+%3D+malloc(SIGSTKSZ),+.ss_size+%3D+SIGSTKSZ,+.ss_flags+%3D+0+%7D%3B%0A++++sigaltstack(%26altstack,+NULL)%3B++//+error+checking+not+shown,+and+I+may+have+misread+the+docs+on+this%0A++++//+or+make+sure+you+never+install+any+signal+handlers.%0A%0A++++insane_caller(argv%5B1%5D)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A'),l:'5',n:'1',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang390,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-xc+-std%3Dgnu11+-Wall+-fno-fast-math+-O3+-fverbose-asm+-fno-unroll-loops+'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+3.9.0',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:80.51470588235294,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+3.9.0',t:'0')),l:'4',m:19.485294117647058,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4).  It runs and works, and more importantly I've inspected the asm output to verify that it does what I wanted it to, so this should actually be safe.  I can't guarantee that it won't break as part of a more complicated program, or with a more complex `return_stackmem`, though.

The padding constants might not be big enough, and there might be an alternate way of making sure the space is big enough.

Without the `DEFEAT_OPTIMIZER` usage in both places, important parts of this really did optimize away.  Have a look on Godbolt!

**`DEFEAT_OPTIMIZER`** gives its operand as an input to an inline asm block with a `"memory"` clobber.  Since the compiler doesn't try to understand the inline asm code (in this case the empty string: zero instructions), it has to have any memory the inline asm might read or write in a consistent state that matches the state of the C abstract machine at that point.  (This always includes the memory pointed to by input operands, and sometimes global variables).  [See also Chandler Carruth's CppCon 2015 talk about microbenchmarking with `perf`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXaxk27zwlk), where he uses the same technique in a macro called ESCAPE to similarly stop the compiler from optimizing away work it thinks isn't necessary.

```
/*****   PLEASE DO NOT EVER DO THIS IN REAL CODE.
*** This relies on a bunch of platform-specific and optimizer-specific hacks.
**  It might compile to asm that's 100% safe now, but on a future compiler
**  or a different platform, or with some source changes, it might not.
***/

#include <signal.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

// you might have seen a macro like this called ESCAPE
#define DEFEAT_OPTIMIZER(p)  asm volatile("" : : "g" (p) : "memory")

// writing this function in assembly language might be necessary to grow the buffer on the fly,
// if it's not possible to work out ahead of time how big it needs to be.

__attribute__((noinline))   // otherwise the strcpy just inlines into the caller (and optimizes away without DEFEAT_OPTIMIZER)
char *return_stackmem(char *input, uint32_t *bufsize)
{
    // Figure out the buffer size somehow;
    *bufsize = 1234;
    // Allocate some padding at the top to make sure the caller doesn't step on
    // any part of the buffer we will use.  Hopefully 128B is enough...
    char *buf = alloca(*bufsize + 128);

    // store into buf;
    strcpy(buf, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");

    // clang normally optimizes away the strcpy because according to C rules,
    // the buffer is dead before anything can look at our return value
    // current gcc doesn't do that, but this is definitely a good idea.
    DEFEAT_OPTIMIZER(buf);
    return buf;
}


void insane_caller(char *input)
{
    uint32_t bufsize;  // not size_t because 4GB is already more than will work.
    char *buffer_below_the_stack = return_stackmem(input, &bufsize);

    // alloca another buffer that entirely covers the first one, placing RSP below the buffer
    char *claim_the_space = alloca(bufsize + 256);    // some extra padding, since the buffer probably wasn't right at the top of the callee's stack frame.
    DEFEAT_OPTIMIZER(claim_the_space);  // make sure the alloca really happens
    assert(claim_the_space < buffer_below_the_stack);
    char *safe_buffer = buffer_below_the_stack;

    printf("safe to make further function calls now, and do stuff like print the buffer: %s\n", safe_buffer);
    // returning destroys all the alloca()ed memory
}

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    stack_t altstack = { .ss_sp = malloc(SIGSTKSZ), .ss_size = SIGSTKSZ, .ss_flags = 0 };
    sigaltstack(&altstack, NULL);  // error checking not shown, and I may have misread the docs on this
    // or make sure you never install any signal handlers.

    insane_caller(argv[1]);
}
```

---

```
peter@tesla:~/src/SO$ gcc -std=gnu11 -O3 buffer_below_the_stack.c
peter@tesla:~/src/SO$ ./a.out 
safe to make further function calls now, and do stuff like print the buffer: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Comment: This is exactly the kind of solution I was looking for! Would you mind explaining how DEFEAT_OPTIMIZER prevents optimizing away strcpy? Would any inline assembly confuse the optimizer?

Comment: @Kalinovcic: added an update.  [Chandler Carruth's 2015 talk about profiling and microbenchmarking with `perf` explains it in more detail](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXaxk27zwlk).

Comment: @BjornA.: Signal handlers run in the context of an existing thread, not in a new thread, so [`pthread_attr_setstack`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_setstack.3.html) doesn't appear to be useful at all.  It doesn't modify the current thread's stack, and it has nothing to do with separating signal handlers from the rest of a thread.

Comment: @PeterCordes If only there was a way to start a new thread with a custom stack...

Comment: @BjornA.: There is, and that's it, but it doesn't help you because signal handlers have nothing to do with threads, and run in the context of the current thread.

Answer (score 6):

This is not solvable in C. Once the function exits, all stack-allocated variables are obliterated. You might be tempted to return a pointer to `alloca()`-provided address from your function, but that would squarely put you into undefined behavior, and you will be a fair game for optimizer.

Comment: It's not just the optimizer. It's also fun and undebuggable things like the occasional interrupt/signal-handler clobbering the free space below the stack-pointer.

Comment: I know it's not solvable in C without doing something unsafe, undefined, etc. If we assume that the optimizer won't try to optimize anything, stack-allocated variables remain on the stack after the function returns, just out of the current stack frame (and even if the optimizer does optimize something, I don't see why it would ever decide to clear the stack frame to zero).

Comment: @EOF I see now that interrupt handlers would cause trouble. Does that make this problem unsolvable in assembly?

Comment: @Kalinovcic: Yes.

Comment: @Kalinovcic Are you running this on bare metal or with an OS? I'd venture a guess that on bare metal you're more likely to see your data preserved when it's out of scope,, but it's simply undefined behavior,, that memory is not yours. You don't own it and can't count on its preservation.

Comment: @EOF Couldn't the problem be solved in assembly by moving the string into place before returning, and then setting the stack pointer past the end of the string, like calling alloca would?

Comment: @Kalinovcic You *do* realize what "returning" means in assembly?

Comment: @Kalinovcic it does not make the problem unsolvable in assembly. The called function can move its return address further down the stack as its first job, ending by telling the caller how much of the stack to pop after using the buffer, which would not be vulnerable from ISRs.

Comment: Yeah. The point is, if the biggest problem is that interrupt handlers would wreck the stack below the stack pointer, I'm suggesting that it could be prevented by moving the string to the stack, and then setting the stack pointer at the end of that string, effectively "returning", but increasing the stack frame of the calling function.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Now you need to write both the caller *and* the callee in (very unusual, slow and fragile) assembly. I'd say inlining the callee is a lot saner.

Comment: @Kalinovcic No, you start by moving the stack pointer down, and copying the return address from further up.

Comment: @EOF The code is computer-generated anyway, but I guess I haven't thought about inlining.

Comment: @EOF some calling conventions do place the stack handling on the caller. I don't see why it would be slower, or fragile but it *is* unusual to split the task beetween caller and called, hence the question.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Callee-cleanup doesn't require copying the return address (which may or may not mess with return-address prediction). It also doesn't disable compiler optimizations wholesale. It doesn't hurt code maintainability.

Comment: @EOF assembly does not have "compiler optimisation". OP was asking how it could be done, and it can, safely..

Comment: @WeatherVane: Unless the OP plans to write the entire program in assembly, compiler optimizations will still be relevant. Considering that a) this kind of assembly will significantly reduce the compiler's ability to reason about the program, and b) the compiler will generally produce considerably better assembly than I expect the OP does, this will hurt performance. Whether this will be "safe" is debatable considering that this is unmaintainable assembly doing non ABI-compliant nonlocal control-flow transfer.

Comment: @EOF in comment the OP says "The main reason is curiosity." If OP wants to experiment on his own computer, that is entirely his prerogative, unhindered by any standards institute or tut-tutting, so long as he knows what *is* acceptable practice. An enquiring mind should be encouraged to experiment.

Comment: Technically, you could solve it in C + inline assembly.  Simply duplicate the stack frame and then go ahead and move everything around, effectively allocating space on the stack above the current return pointer and then putting the return pointer and saved frame pointer at the bottom with EBP and ESP set appropriately before heading back into the remainder of the C function.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer: I came up with a solution that only uses inline-asm to stop the optimizer from eliminating "unused" alloca, or eliminating stores into an alloca that's returned.  It requires an unlimited-size red-zone, but that's achieveable in user-space (I think).

Comment: @DavidHoelzer: I think I misunderstood your suggestion the first time: are you suggesting that the callee copies everything between the caller's EBP and caller's ESP?  How does the caller manage to return to its own parent with the correct ESP?  Even if it ends with LEAVE (or equivalent), that will set ESP = the modified EBP.  I think your only hope is my first interpretation of what you said, which is to try to modify ESP but not EBP, and hope the caller is only accessing its stack frame with EBP-relative addressing modes.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I think I've solved this, at least for user-space :)  I totally agree about encouraging experimentation.  The best way to understand the why the rules are what they are is to find out how to break them, and what happens.

Answer (score -2):

How about using a static char* inside the function, and then malloc() memory to hold the string?

```
char* foo(some args, I guess)
{
    static char *str;
    ...
    if ((str = malloc(somelen)) == NULL)
        return NULL;

    ....
    return str;
}
```

It's not a good solution, but at least it's legal C.

Comment: The length isn't always the same; this solution would therefore require the function to reallocate str when it's too small, which is the same as just allocating the buffer every time. Besides, malloc can't be used at all, static variables aren't thread safe, and aren't on the stack.

Comment: Downvote: OP says he doesn't want to use `malloc()`. Your answer uses `malloc`, therefore it doesn't answer OP's question and is off topic. Please pay attention to constraints in a question you want to answer.

Comment: @FUZxxl I disagree. The original question was stupid and the OP knew it, at least partly. My "answer", which would have been a comment if comments had formatting, was an attempt to lead OP back to code sanity.

Comment: What's the point of having `str` be `static` if you don't even look at it's existing value?  Besides not even being close to what the OP is asking for, it's not even a good solution to any problem.  If you're going to suggest anything, suggest using a macro that can use alloca inside the "caller" (see my answer; feel free to expand on / write example code for the macro idea, or any other idea.  Maybe a gigantic static buffer that you use part of and return a pointer to?).

Comment: @BjornA. If OP's requirements are insane, then the correct answer is “it's not possible under these requirements” and look what answer got accepted. Ignoring the question however leads to downvotes.

Comment: @Kalinovcic Note that C11 introduces thread local variables which are like thread-safe `static` variables.